# Displaying a notification when bluetooth is disconnected - Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create a program that will display a `notification` to the user if a **Blue tooth** device suddenly comes out of range from my Android device. I currently have the following code but no notification is displayed.

I was wondering if it was possible I shouldn't use `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` because I believe the `bluetooth` stack would be expecting packets that state a disconnect is requested. My requirements state that the bluetooth device will disconnect without warning.

Thank you for any assistance!

BluetoothNotification.java:
//This is where the notification is created.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class BluetoothNotification extends Activity
{
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** Define configuration for our notification */
    int icon = R.drawable.logo;
    CharSequence tickerText = "This is a sample notification";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Sample notification";
    CharSequence contentText = "This notification has been generated as a result of BT Disconnecting";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothNotification.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    /** Initialize the Notification using the above configuration */
    final Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    /** Retrieve reference from NotificationManager */

    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);


    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    finish();
}    
}
```

Snippet from OnCreate: //Located in Controls.java

```
IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
```

Snippet from Controls.java:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
               //Device has disconnected
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) 
                    getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }

    }

};
```

Comment: Great job and wounderful question,.. And an interesting question.. Thanks, and if u got the answer means, post it!.. I too trying for that Mr. Ryan

Answer (score 0):

What is the link between your BroadCastReceiver and your Activity ?

There is no need for this activity, put everything in your broadcast receiver to display the notification.

Comment: So you're saying there's no need to create the BluetoothNotification.java file? Simply place all configuration code for notification in the "if" statement?

Comment: I am new to Android programming so I was using this as a sample.

Comment: Under "getActivity" I receive an error "The method getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (new BroadcastReceiver(){}, int, Intent, int)"

All I have done is copy over what is done in BluetoothNotification.java into the if statement.

Comment: What do you want to do when your notification is clicked ? That's what you describe using a PendingIntent. Do you want to go to an activity or use a service ? Usually you will open an activity, google an example.

Comment: I would like upon the notification to be selected, the user to be returned to Controls.java

Comment: What is Control. Please try something by yourself at this point

Comment: You asked a question and I answered it :) I got rid of the errors but not sure if it works. Will have to verify tomorrow.

Comment: This is example is not real life enough, you always need to make the activity respond to this.  I can't see the link between receiver and activity.. it seems impossible to me. Android Java is very hard to program for.  in windows I would just have an event on my activity... done, simple.And in windows I can access all the properties of the activity from my receiver event.  This is waay over complicated.